# Typeahead- Add link to results when no direct match is found

Tags: javascript, typeahead.js, typeahead

#### Summary:

To add a link to the search results when no direct match is found.

#### Detail:

I want to add a link to the search results when no direct match is found. My thought was to try and detect a direct match then add the link to the results, assuming its not already there.

A good example of this is Github's milestone search on an issue. If you search for a milestone that doesn't exist a link is presented to create one instead.

#### Flow:

- User inputs text

  - If a direct match **IS** found - no link displayed
  - If **NO** direct match found - display link to create object

I'm just not sure how or if I can detect a direct match and then add a datum. Any help on how to implement this or if it's possible would be appreciated?

Comment: If somebody bumps into this... As discussed on git hub you can modify typeahead to achieve this. https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/1081